# Evaluate $108\over x$ divided by $3y$, where $x = 9$ and $y = 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $108\over x$ divided by $3y$, where $x = 9$ and $y = 3$.

My daughter's 6th grade math teacher says the answer is $12$. Going by the order rules, he might be right $({12\over 3} = 4;4 \times 3 = 12)$. 
My question is: Is $3y$ multiplication?

Comment: Yes, $3y$ is short for $3\times y$. But $\left(\frac{108}{9}\right)$ divided by $3\cdot3$ equals $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: If the problem was $\frac{108}{x}\div3y$,
Your child's teacher may have evaluated it as $(\frac{108}{x}\div3)\times y$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Notice, $3y$ is not multiplied by $\left(\frac{108}{x}\right)$, it is divided as follows  $$\frac{\left(\frac{108}{x}\right)}{3y}=\frac{108}{3xy}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $3y$ is multiplication of $3$ and $y$.  The usual reading of the problem would be $$\dfrac {\frac{108}x}{3y}=\dfrac {108}{3xy}=\dfrac {108}{3 \cdot 9 \cdot 3}=\dfrac {108}{81}=\dfrac 43$$